# using a function to remove graphs in c3

Tags: javascript, c3.js

How can I handle a chart#.destroy() when the charts are created inside a function like:

```
function create(i){
    chart = 'chart' + i
    chart = c3.generate(...)
}
create(1)
create(2)
create(3)
```

so that it creates chart1, chart2, chart3.

I am trying to have a button call a function: clear_chart:

```
function clear_chart(){
    for(i=1; i<4; i++){
       chart = 'chart' +i
       chart.destroy()
    }
}
```

I get an error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you're not selecting a chart doing this:

```
chart = 'chart' +i
```

You can also remove the same line from the create method as is not doing anything on your code. You're assigning a value to the chart var and then reassigning it when generating the chart the name of the var is still "chart".

The easiest way of working with chart objects is storing them in an array and using  them afterwards:

```
var charts = [];
function create(){
    var chart = c3.generate(...);
    charts.push(chart);
}
//call create function...

function clear_chart(){
    for(i = 1; i < 4; i++){
        var chart = charts[i - 1]; 
        chart.destroy();     
    }
}
```

If you want to select just a specific one through their name, I suggest taking a look at jQuery selectors (if possible to add jQuery to your project) or d3 select functions.

Comment: An additional use case ---- I'm trying to use the clear_chart to continually redraw my charts but I keep getting an error that 

***Uncaught ReferenceError: chart is not defined***

` function redraw(){
clear_chart()
create_chart()
}

setInterval(redraw(), 1000)`

Comment: You can do the same approach with an array that I mentioned in my answer but you don't need to clear and then create it again. You can just update the data on it via load() method (https://c3js.org/reference.html#api-load) and call flush() to redraw it (https://c3js.org/reference.html#api-flush). The important here is refactoring your code so you have a reference to chart objects to call it's functions. The undefined should be fixed on my clear_chart method now. Also, make sure you're not getting the arrayOutOfBounds error on the loop iteration on the clear chart function)